# Broken mdadm RAID after hard drive firmware update

Tags: raid, mdadm

I updated the firmware on the two hard drives in my raid array, and now the raid array does not seem to work.   I'm running Kubuntu 12.10.

Here is the output of some things I tried:

```
sudo mdadm --assemble --scan
mdadm: failed to add /dev/sdb1 to /dev/md/1: Invalid argument
mdadm: failed to add /dev/sda1 to /dev/md/1: Invalid argument
mdadm: failed to RUN_ARRAY /dev/md/1: Invalid argument

sudo mdadm --query --detail /dev/md* 
mdadm: md device /dev/md1 does not appear to be active.
```

Any ideas of what to do next?

Comment: check `dmesg` for errors.

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion.   I get the following:

    [ 5353.561872] md: sdb1 does not have a valid v1.2 superblock, not importing!
    [ 5353.561885] md: md_import_device returned -22
    [ 5353.562033] md: sda1 does not have a valid v1.2 superblock, not importing!
    [ 5353.562044] md: md_import_device returned -22

Comment: That sounds bad. What does fdisk think about the disks? Do you happen to have its (or similar) output from before?

Comment: I'm not sure what happened... Updating the firmware of the disks should not have modified any content but obviously something went wrong.   I'm currently in the process of rebuilding the array (issuing the exact same command as when I created it in the first place: sudo mdadm --create /dev/md1 --metadata 1.2 --level=10 --layout=f2 --raid-devices=2 /dev/sda1 /dev/sdb1).   My understanding is that mdadm should see that there is already a raid array there and fix things... I'll report back in 325 minutes when resync is done!

Comment: Well, unfortunately things are not better.   As far as I can see, it looks like there is an array with nothing in it.   Now, running mdadm --assemble --scan does nothing!

Comment: It is to late now, but this looks like a mirror. Next time only upgrade a disk from the mirror, then check if it still works. If it does not then you still have all the data.

Comment: I just ran into a similar issue. Basically, I had a bunch of disk images from an old RAID that recently failed, and I shrunk the filesystem, shrunk the disk images, and rewrote the partition tables. However, I forgot to run the mdadm command to shrink the size of the array, so now I'm here.